# Finding the Probability Density of a Linear Combination

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Given the probability density

$f(x)= \begin{cases}{y} && {0\le\>y\le\>1} \\ {1} && {1\>\le\>y\>\le\>1.5} \\ {0} && {\textrm{elsewhere}}\end{cases} $

How would I find the density for

$U=10Y-4$

Comment: Find the distribution of $U$ then differentiate

Comment: You have: $f(\color{red}x) = \operatorname {some function of } \color{red}y$.  You may want to reconsider your choice of symbols.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following result to get pdf of one variable from pdf of other variable related by some equation:
$$f_X(x)dx=f_Y(y)dy$$

$f_X$ and $f_Y$ are pdfs of $X$ and $Y$. $\frac{dy}{dx}$ can be found from the equation you have.